# Много «душных заявлений», но мало понятно

Tags: стилистика, кавычки, смысл

Непонятен смысл, вкладываемый в понятное слово *душный*. Можете пояснить, что это определение значит в контексте данной цитаты? Есть ли ему синоним?

> Заявления «коллективного Запада» о международной изоляции России с каждым днем становятся всё смешнее... За последние полгода мы прочитали много поразительных, одинаковых, нелогичных и откровенно
> душных заявлений.

Answer (score 3):

Из комментария: *Совместить душное со смешным может щекотка...*

Вот полный абзац из [статьи](https://inforuss.info/teper-ssha-dazhe-ne-shelohnetsya-izolirovannaya-rossiya-priblizhaetsya-k-granitsam-ssha-putin-prepodal-vashingtonu-urok/).

> Заявления «коллективного Запада» о международной изоляции России с каждым днем становятся все смешнее, но есть одно «но». Сначала это был просто популизм и казался не самой удачной шуткой — иногда даже смешной, — но постепенно он превратился в дешевую капеллу. За последние полгода мы прочитали много поразительных, одинаковых, нелогичных и откровенно душных заявлений.

Здесь слово ["смешной"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9) имеет второе или третье значение (это видно по контексту):
вызывающий насмешку, ироническое отношение своей нелепостью, несообразностью и т. п.;
такой, который нельзя воспринимать серьёзно.

Вкупе с особенным значением слова "душный" (синонимы: тягостный, гнетущий, неприятный, тяготящий, давящий) такое совмещение, думаю, вполне адекватно.

**Дополнение**

В комментариях я уже указала подходящие по смыслу примеры: ***душные времена, душные проблемы.***
Подходящее значение для слова ["душный"](http://rudictionary.com/efremova/Dushnyj-22931.html#gsc.tab=0) имеется и в ТС Ефремовой:
2) *перен.* Оказывающий тяжелое моральное воздействие на человеческую личность; гнетущий.

Вот еще из Нацкорпуса:
***Чтение ― душное** донельзя. Сплошь документы ― как есть, сырьем;

Согласитесь, когда монашка вот так запросто средь бела дня приставляет вам к носу тяжелый, пахнущий смертью ствол, то всякого может хватить ледяная оторопь и **душное недоумение**;

Помню, Белкин **сочинял что-то в прозе**, реалистическое и **душное**, и мне даже сейчас помнится рассказ о том, как мать послала малолетнего сына стоять в очереди за постным маслом;

...изобразить так: вначале шли широкие спирали сюжета, потом они сужались, как бы убыстряясь, создавая **душное предощущение несчастья**...*

Comment: Спасибо за мнение (и с ним соглашусь), но далее... придётся повториться: в цитате речь о заявлениях, чтобы они собой не представляли. И лишь в сочетании **душные заявления** я увидел смысловую пробоину или несостыковку, допущенную автором.  /// P.S. За увековечивание коммента в ответе не знаю как и благодарить.

Comment: Я расширила свой ответ: добавила ссылку и примеры. Мне кажется, что нет никакой несостыковки: душные заявления = неприятные заявления. P. S. после P. S. Не знаю, как реагировать... Разве я сделала что-то предосудительное, использовав кусочек вашего комментария?

Answer (score 2):

> Душный человек, душнила – сленговое определение неприятного, скучного, мелочного и нудного человека. ([memepedia.ru](https://memepedia.ru/chto-takoe-dushnyj-chelovek/#:%7E:text=%D0%94%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA.,%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%2E))

Поэтому, полагаю, возможно прочитать приведенную вами цитату так:

> За последние полгода мы прочитали много поразительных, одинаковых, нелогичных и откровенно неприятных, скучных, мелочных и нудных заявлений.

Comment: Разговор с *душным* человеком, допустим, может быть душным, но заявления-то «от Запада» как? Они не требуют участия в диалоге: не читай и не слушай.

Comment: Я согласен с вашей оценкой. На мой взгляд это стилистический вопрос. Политические заявления не могут быть «душными», по-моему так же как и «смешными». Однако язык пропаганды подразумевает максимальное эмоциональное вовлечение читателя.

Answer (score 2):

Словарь Ефремовой:
2. перен. Оказывающий тяжёлое моральное воздействие на человеческую личность; гнетущий.

Словарь Кузнецова:
4) **Давящий**, гнетущий.
*Душная атмосфера яростных споров.

Душная обстановка казарменной жизни.*

Стоит заметить, что в более старых словарях этого значения нет.

Мне сразу был ясен смысл — те, которые душат (морально). Но в словарях так не напишут.

Comment: Да, похоже. В поддержку: 1. Сравнивать все-таки нельзя: то были совершенно выморочные, бесперспективные, *душные времена*. [М. С. Харитонов. Стенография конца века. Из дневниковых записей (2008)] 2. В эти минуты он ― самый обыкновенный житель земли, которому незачем было вчера расстраивать отца из-за каких-то стихов, которому надо решать насущные *проблемы*, такие же *душные*, как эти минуты под безжалостным солнцем. [Ю. И. Лунин. Три века русской поэзии // «Волга», 2016]

Comment: Предваряя оценку заявлений, автор огульно называет их смешными. Совместить душное со смешным может щекотка, но никак не текст, убрать с глаз который можно в любую минуту.

Comment: @shampar Не, оно нормально сочетается по смыслу, да, есть контраст. Вполне можно угрожать, тогда как эти угрозы могут казаться кому-то смешными. Слово "откровенно" (не скрыто) подсказывает, что здесь это значение. Этот текст точно не для сленга.